# List does not take parameters #another reason

Tags: java, arraylist

i named my class `ArrayList` and when I wrote this

```
List< String> list = new ArrayList< String>();
```

it reminded me that I cant do that by this `List` does not take parameters

after changing the class name no more problem.

Somebody know why?

Comment: You mean you implemented an `ArrayList<T>` yourself?

Answer (score 2):

The error states that the class you created `ArrayList` does not take parameters because you did not specify a parameter to it as you are using on your code `List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();`

The `<String>` part of your code right after the `Arraylist` is your problem.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                                 | 
                                 |-here
```

Your class should be created as `public class ArrayList<T>` the `<T>` part of the code is the parameter that compiler is complaining about.

But even if you do that it would complain after that, because your class should implement an List to work but this is another question.

Also read about [Generics](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_generics.htm)

This I'm saying based on what you said on your question. If you actually implemented the `java.util.ArrayList` the answer given by @CommuSoft would be better.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the default `java.util.ArrayList` and `List<T>` definitely takes generic type parameters into account, the code is valid. See this [**jdoodle**](http://jdoodle.com/a/hH).

In case you implemented an `ArrayList<T>` yourself, you will need to provide the sourcecode. In that case the signature of the class should read something like:

```
public class ArrayList<T> implements List<T> {
    //...
}
```

If you implemented the `ArrayList<T>` correctly, however the only proble is that Java can have an issue with disambiguation. In that case, you will need to be more explicit. Or you are explicit on the `List` part:

```
import your.ArrayList;
//...
java.util.List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Or on your `ArrayList` part:

```
import java.util.List;
//...
List<String> list = new your.ArrayList<String>();
```